gulp nunjucksRender not compiling html files
I am trying to render nunjucks .njk files into HTML file
This gulpfile.js...
var gulp = require("gulp");
var nunjucksRender = require("gulp-nunjucks-render");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

gulp.task("html", function() {
    return gulp.src('./views/*.njk')
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: ['./views']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});

...is not rendering any html files, with no errors either.
I tried to run on Terminal the command 'gulp html'
It responded with
Starting 'html'...
and it said
Finished 'html' after 7.85 ms
No errors but no html files compiled

How you make your gulp tasks run...matters.  Show more code including "how" your gulp logic is supposed to run.
